# Getting phpMyAdmin into project and not causing errors in subversion

Tags: svn, phpmyadmin

I have a project that includes a copy of phpMyAdmin.

I do development locally and use subversion for version control.

When a new release of phpMyAdmin comes out I have to take all of the files from the new phpMyAdmin release and move them into the exiting files in my project.  If I copy the entire directory I get errors the next time I commit to the server.

Is there an easier way of dealing with this?  Is there something I can do to quickly get the updates from phpMyAdmin into my project without causing problems in my local working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I'd recommend downloading a copy of [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), which has a section on [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html). You use these to import third-party source code into a Subversion repository/project.

Comment: Thanks...my situation is a bit easier than the example they give int the Vendor branches chapter but it solved the problem.